# How to set values for one column based on another?

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

How to set values for one column based on another?

> Goal: When in the DB table the column Remote = table SO in the column
> Thrunode -> Set in the table DB the column customer = table SO
>
> *DB = tbl_db_collecting
>
> SO = tb_systemshc*

**sql:**

```
UPDATE tbl_db_collecting SET
    tbl_db_collecting.customer = tb_systemshc.environment
FROM tb_systemshc
WHERE tbl_db_collecting.lower(remote) = tb_systemshc.lower(thrunode)
```

**output:**

```
SQL Error [3F000]: ERROR: schema "tbl_db_collecting" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
update tbl_db_collecting
   set customer = tb_systemshc.environment
  from tb_systemshc
 where lower(tbl_db_collecting.remote) = lower(tb_systemshc.thrunode);
```

When you write `tbl_db_collecting.lower(remote)`, PostgreSQL parses that as if you are looking for a `lower()` function defined in schema `tbl_db_collecting`.